# Opam circuit where Vout =(V11/3 + V25/2)1/3

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

Hi i need to design an opam circuit where

[image: Circuit requirment]

But I can't find anywhere where I can get exponential outputs can you please help!

Comment: Look at log-antilog circuits

Comment: Keep looking. Improve your google fu.

Comment: Or even search the site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66011/how-to-electronically-generate-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions

Answer (score 0):

Anti-Log (exponential) op amp circuits are insanely tricky. Look up an exponential converter on rene schmitz website for a detailed tutorial that uses an op-amp. You need to have a non-linear element (diode or transistor) in the feedback path, however those active components have nasty temperature dependencies. The simplest log circuit has a single diode in the feedback path and an input resistor into the inverting summing node.