# How to electronically generate exponentially growing sinusoidal signal

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transistors, analog, oscillator

How can we generate exponentially growing sinusoidal signal (further describes below equation and ) using a simple analogue circuit (e.g. op-amps, transistors, or oscillator)?

Mathematically, \$v(t)=C_0e^{rt}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T} t ),\$ where \$ r>0,\$ and \$ t<n_0 T\$

or, visually something like this (amplitude can be very small)

[image]

I already read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66011/how-to-electronically-generate-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions), but I am looking for generating an oscillating signal.

Comment: Build an op-amp oscillator that's held in a starting state by analog switches, and that has no AGC to limit oscillation.  Switch it to the run state for 5ms, and then switch it back.

Comment: Or just look over [this link](https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/precision_adcs/w/documents/2866/adas1000-crystal-oscillator-startup) as that's pretty much how some oscillators start up.

Comment: Generate an exponentially rising signal and use an oscillator and multiplier to produce an exponentially rising sine wave. Trigger the exponential growth at a zero cross of the sine wave. Next question is how to generate an exponentially rising signal.

Comment: super-regenerative radio receivers do this, however they generally switch off more gently, since reciprocating energy in L&C is substantial and takes some time to dissipate. http://www.eix.co.uk/Articles/Radio/Welcome.htm

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emitter-coupled Franklin oscillator with switched power supply.
[image: oscillator]

Answer (score 1):

Bias a WEIN_BRIDGE oscillator with charge on each of the two capacitors.

Then enable the opamp output.

A CA3080 has this Enable ability.

===========================

Since you need to impose Initial Voltages on the 2 capacitors, this becomes a Switched Capacitor design. Plan on using two analog multiplexors per capacitor, or 4 total multiplexors.

Comment: This is not a complete explanation and doesn't even have links to external information

Answer (score 1):

The following oscillator should work with precision op amps (low offset voltage), as long as the values of \$r\$ and \$T\$ do not need to be very precise.

[image: Oscillator schematic]

Defining \$\omega=2\pi/T\$, I get \$r=\frac{R_4/R_3}{2 R_2 C_2}\$ and \$\omega^2=\frac{(R_4/R_3) (R_5/R_6)+(R_4/R_6)+(R_5/R_6)}{R_1 C_1
   R_2 C_2}-r^2\$. SPICE simulation seems to give the expected behavior using mostly ideal op amps with the switch switching at \$t=1\$ ms:

```
.subckt sw_spdt 1 2 3
R1 1 2 R={time < 1ms ? 10Meg : 1m}
R2 2 3 R={time < 1ms ? 1m : 10Meg}
R3 1 3 100Meg
.ends
```

A plot of V(/OUT) is shown below:

[image: Simulation plot]

The initial voltage can be chosen to charge C0, and flipping the switch starts the oscillator. After a few periods, the op amps will start to behave differently and probably approach equilibrium again (0V). The output voltage can be divided if a smaller voltage is desired, and another switch could be used to ground the output at some time \$t=n_0 T\$.

### Explanation

The objective function \$v(t)=V_0 e^{r t}\cos(\omega t)\$ is the unique (nontrivial) real solution to the IVP

\$v(t)=-\left(v''(t)-2 r v'(t)\right)/(r^2+\omega^2),\,v(0)=V_0.\$

Op amps are used to take the appropriate derivatives and connected in a feedback loop. Switching the voltage pulls the system out of equilibrium and starts the oscillator.